# Inserting many rows causes locking conflicts with Hibernate and Postgres, leaving the table empty

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

We are benchmarking some queries to see if they will still work reliably for "a lot of" data. (1 million isn't that much to be honest, but Postgres already fails here, so it evidently is.)

Our Java code to call this queries looks something like that:

```java
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
@Resource
private UserTransaction utx;

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    this.utx.begin();
    for (int inserts = 0; inserts  < 50_000; inserts ++) {
        em.createNativeQuery(SQL_INSERT).executeUpdate();
    }
    this.utx.commit();


    for (int parameter = 0; parameter  < 25; parameter ++) 
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Assert.assertNotNull(this.em.createNativeQuery(SQL_SELECT).getResultList());
        System.out.println(i + " iterations \t" + parameter  + "\t" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + "ms");
    }
}
```

Or with plain JDBC:

```java
Connection connection = //...


for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for (int inserts = 0; inserts  < 50_000; inserts ++) {
        try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement();) {
            statement.execute(SQL_INSERT);
        }
    }

    for (int parameter = 0; parameter  < 25; parameter ++) 
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement();) {
            statement.execute(SQL_SELECT);
        }
        System.out.println(i + " iterations \t" + parameter  + "\t" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + "ms");
    }
}
```

The queries we tried were a simple `INSERT` into a table with JSON and a `INSERT` over two tables with about 25 lines. The `SELECT` has one or two JOINs and is pretty easy. One set of queries is (I had to anonymize the SQL else I wouldn't have been allowed to post it):

```sql
CREATE TABLE ts1.p (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT p_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE ts1.m(
    pId integer NOT NULL,
    mId character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    a1 character varying(50),
    a2 character varying(50),
    CONSTRAINT m_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pI, mId)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE ts1.seq_p;

/* 
 * SQL_INSERT 
 */

WITH p AS (
    INSERT INTO  ts1.p (id)
           VALUES (nextval('ts1.seq_p'))
    RETURNING id AS pId
)
INSERT INTO ts1.m(pId, mId, a1, a2)
      VALUES ((SELECT pId from p), 'M1', '11', '12'),
             ((SELECT pId from p), 'M2', '13', '14'),
             /*  ... about 20 to 25 rows of values */

/* 
 * SQL_SELECT 
 */

WITH userInput (mId, a1, a2) AS (
  VALUES
    ('M1', '11', '11'),
    ('M2', '12', '15'),
    /* ... about "parameter" rows of values */
)
SELECT m.pId, COUNT(m.a1) AS matches
FROM userInput u
    LEFT JOIN ts1.m m ON (m.mId) = (u.mId)
WHERE (m.a1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM u.a1) AND
    (m.a2 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM u.a2) OR
    (m.a1 IS NULL AND m.a2 IS NULL)
GROUP BY m.pId

/* plus HAVING, additional WHERE clauses etc. according to the use case, but that just speeds up the query */
```

When executing, we get the following output (the values are supposed to rise steadly and linearly):

```
271ms
414ms
602ms
820ms
995ms
1192ms
1396ms
1594ms
1808ms
1959ms
110ms
33ms
14ms
10ms
11ms
10ms
21ms
8ms
13ms
10ms
```

As you can see, after some value (usually at around 300,000 to 500,000 inserts) the time needed for the query drops significantly. Sadly we can't really debug what the result is at that point (other than that it's not null), but we assume it's an empty list, because the database tables are empty.

Let me repeat that: **After half a million `INSERTS`, Postgres clears tables.**

Of course that's not acceptable at all.

We tried different queries, all of easy to medium difficulty, and all produced this behavior, so we assume it's not the queries.

We thought that maybe the sequence returned a value too high for a column `integer`, so we droped and recreated the sequence.

Once there was this exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException : FEHLER: Verklemmung (Deadlock) entdeckt
  Detail: Prozess 1620 wartet auf AccessExclusiveLock-Sperre auf Relation 2001098 der Datenbank 1937678; blockiert von Prozess 2480.
```

Which I'm entirely unable to translate. I guess it's something like:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException : ERROR: Jamming? Clamping? Constipation? (Deadlock) found
```

But I don't think this error has anything to do with the clearing of the table. We just tested against the wrong database, so multiple queries were run on the same table. Normally we have one database per benchmark test.

Of course it's important that we find out what the error is, so that we can decide if there is any risk to our customers losing their data (because again, on error the database empties some table of its choice).

**Postgres version:** `PostgreSQL 10.6, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit`

We tried `PostgreSQL 9.6.11, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit`, too. And we never had the same problem there (even though that could just be luck, since it's not 100% reproducible).

Do you have any idea what the error is? Or how we could debug it? The entire benchmark test runs for an hour, so there is no immediate feedback.

Comment: I can assure you I have inserted hundreds of millions of rows into Postgres and it never "cleared" any table for me. I would suspect your obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") to be the culprit here. Try the same with plain JDBC. The fact that you are getting lock errors seems to indicate that your obfuscation layer does not do this in a single transaction but runs this from multiple concurrent sessions with the effect that they block each other.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I try to set something up. The problem is that a long execution time and no guaranteed reproducablity make the issue kind of hard to verify.

Comment: You have a dead lock on the table. How do you generate the primary key? And you insert 50k records in one transaction maybe you should use batch inserts.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Why should Hibernate do anything? It's native queries not ORM. I know that you don't like ORM but it's not always the problem

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Hibernate does some caching in the background and flushes its internal buffers whenever it thinks it's necessary - outside of the control of the program. Plus: I am 100% sure that Postgres does not do such things as "clearing tables" during many inserts. And it doesn't lock itself if only a single transaction is used. So it must be something in the software stack. Either Hibernate opening more multiple sessions/transactions that conflict with each other or something in the way the code is called. The problem shown is most certainly not caused by Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Caching is only true for JPQL not for Native queries (SQL). Native queries are bypassed to JDBC. But I'm also sure that it's not a PostgreSQL problem

Comment: Can you please show the SQL statements too

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I had no idea that that could lead to any errors, but in the actual code I insert the 50k record in batches of 10k.

Comment: How is the primary key generated? and please show the sql statements

Comment: There is one case where postgres will actually clear a table - if postgres crashes and the table is unlogged.  I really doubt that is the issue here, though.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I added my SQL query. My colleague has the same problem with entirely different queries, though (but the same amount of data and read / write access).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The plain JDBC test just had the same drop in execution time as the Hibernate tests before. So it seems it's actually not Hibernate.

Comment: @Jeremy How do you figure that's not what's happening? We accidentally ran the same tests just now against the same database, and both of our tables got cleared at about the same time (we were using differente schemas and tables).

Comment: Do you have an unlogged table and is postgres crashing?  It doesn't seem like it's crashing because you are continuing to run queries.  Unlogged is not the default, so you would have had to specify that option when you created the table.

Comment: What is the cache size of your sequence? And why do you use a CTE? You can get the last value from the sequence with select currval('ts1.seq_p'); I would suggest you try to remove the CTEs and set the cache size of the sequence to 50 or 100

Comment: @SimonMartinelli CTE just seemed more correct, because `currval()` might have the ID of another inserted value. The cache size is the default one, so 1 for Postgres. I' try the suggested changes.

Comment: At least on Oracle DB a cache size of 1 can be a huge performance blocker

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Only the time for the SELECTs is measured (because in reality the INSERTs are executed over the years of using the software), so I guess I don't care for slow INSERTs. However weirdly enough using `currval()` in the INSERT sped up the execution time of the SELECT o_O And the tables never got cleared (during admittedly only 4 runs).

Comment: A deadlock is almost always an application error. If you get one, you most probably have other processes running that also write to the database (and I would suspect _that_ process to also clean out your table). `currval()` will **never** return the ID generated for another transaction.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't think the deadlock (if it is a deadlock, I'm skeptical with the made-up words in the German error message) has anything to do with the problem at hand. Because firstly the exception was thrown only once (and only when several of us accidentally used the same database), while we could reproduce the actual problem even when run against local databases; and secondly because table clearing is not really something which screams “deadlock” to me.

Comment: A deadlock is something that doesn't occur always as it heavily depends on the order execution. The fact that it occurred once strongly suggests you have parallel processes running somewhere - and I suspect those being the culprit. Btw. what is your **exact** Postgres version? (`select version();` will tell you)

Comment: This type of question isn't very well suited for Stackoverflow because of the constant back and forth and discussion that is needed to find the root cause in your Java code. Maybe posting this to the [Postgres performance mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/list/) is a better way to get a solution to your problem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's just it: the deadlock does NOT occur strongly. It occurred ONCE. When we made a mistake and tested against the wrong database. The clearing of the tables occurs often. The version is `PostgreSQL 10.6, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit`. I **could not** get the same problem on `PostgreSQL 9.6.11, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name And to be honest, I don't see how that can _possibly_ be Java's fault. There's absolutely no logic there, it's just a loop and concatenating some strings to get a query. So the actual question is how can as little as half a million queries brake a database?

Comment: The simple answer is: inserting half a million rows most definitely does not "break the database" - it has to be something in your Java code or your environment. I regularly insert tens of millions of rows for testing purposes using similar approaches (mainly plain SQL, sometimes using Java). Postgres never "clears out" a table.

Comment: Based on your Postgres version, you are using Windows - one constant source of problems with Postgres on Windows are anti-virus programs that interfere with writing the data from Postgres. Try to exclude Postgres and the Postgres data directory from being scanned by whatever anti-virus program you are using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Anti-virus seemed a really good idea since it worked locally, but sadly there is no such program on the database server's machine. Would be very weird for it to clear out tables, too.

Comment: The anti-virus program is intercepting write calls and as such it can absolutely "clear out" a table if it thinks that at one point the write to the data directory is malicious and stops them. What is the setting of the [fsync](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-FSYNC) parameter?